# fail to save time to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, time

I have a simple ruby on rails app with a micropost model which has content and tt (which I want to be some time entered by the user - in migration file it is defined as `t.time :tt`). I use a simple form

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.time_field :tt %>
<% end %>
```

Then I use strong parameters in controller

```
def micropost_params
  params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :tt)
end
```

But when it's saved to the database, tt is nil, even if I enter 0 in the time_field. What's the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe problem not in strong params. Log them. Perhaps problem when saving in differ in types.

Comment: I think you're right. the problem is in different types, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I never see `t.time :tt`. Try `t.datetime :tt`

Comment: There is indeed a `time` attribute which accepts time only.

Comment: Oh! I don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I never seen something like `time_field` in `form_for`.Perhaps you can try using `time_select`

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.time_select :tt %>
<% end %>
```

For more options with `time_select`,see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select)**